# Include AD domain admins group in Linux sudoers?

Tags: linux, networking, permissions, sudo, active-directory

I'm working in a company whose network is configured through a Win Server Active Directory, with hundreds Windows of computers connected to the local domain.
We are doing some tests to start introducing Linux machines. I already installed one with Linux Mint, connected it to the local domain with Likewise, and we can log in to these computers with network users.

However, unlike in Windows environment in which users in Domain Admin group automatically have administrator rights, in Linux they don't have root access nor can they sudo.
I believe that give them sudo rights would be the easiest but how can I add a network group in the sudoers file?

Answer (score 2):

Edit the sudoer similar to the follow (from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LikewiseOpen):

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
%OMG\\team-alpha ALL=(ALL)ALL
```

Where `%OMG\\team-alpha` is the domain admin group.

Comment: `%OMG` would be the name of the Domain, right?

Comment: That's correct, the `%` tells it that it's a group, instead of a user.